# Google Earth to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I've been emailed the following https://earth.google.com/web/@30.0867484,-97.29304982,148.9215598a,284.21410691d,31.95361314y,0h,0t,0r . Is there a way to turn this into a Google map?

I have been looking at Google Earth Pro but can't see a way to load this. If I could, it I could export it as a KML file and then do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFNuYFyjOx4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- go to **[My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/)**

  [image: 0]
- click on **<kbd>`+ CREATE A NEW MAP`</kbd>** button
- copy coordinates from your link **`30.0867484,-97.29304982`**
- paste them into the search bar and hit **<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>** key
- optional: zoom in and change to satellite view
- click on **3 dots**
- select **Export to KML/KMZ**
- tick the **KML instead of KMZ** checkbox and **Download**

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

- to import KML file into My Maps click on **Import**

[image: 0]

Comment: its not exactly the same question. Could you add anything onto how to import this into google maps please?

Comment: @user61629 added

Comment: Thank you, just realized that ONLY the first 2 numbers are the coordinates.